# Ignore task if canceled (JavaFX)

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency

I found here a lot of posts about canceling a Task within a JavaFX application.
The suggested way was to launch cancel method and check isCancelled() return value.

My problem arises when there are a lot of things to ignore.

For example.

```
   myTask = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            if (!isCancelled()){
               doSomething();
            }
            return null;
        }
   };
   new Thread(myTask).start();
```

But doSomething() method is updating a lot of UI components / Databases / other background task. How can I ignore / cancel all the stuff within the method doSomething()? Until now I had very easy stuff to update, and I just checked before each one the return value of isCancelled().

I will be glad for your help,
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is going to help you:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Comment: Basic isCancelled()...

Comment: But, where in your code you handle cancelled?

Comment: There is no way to interrupt a database call.  Background tasks which you have written should handle InterruptedException by exiting gracefully.  You may also want to add `isCancelled` checks to long tasks.

Comment: @VGR Interrupt a task and catch it will be good practice? And regarding the isCancelled() before long tasks - what if I have many of them? Before each one I need to check that?

Comment: @zlakad Why does it matter?

Comment: Yes, you want to check isCancelled between each of your tasks.  If possible, check it inside each of those tasks.

Comment: @VGR - What if some task is currently doing some DB job, and meanwhile another same task start to work? We will cancel by launching cancel method with the new task, but the previous can think that he is still living when checking isCancelled(). the same task as him (assume we saved it in some class variable). I'm thinking about saving each task a key in some hashmap, and when he will return from his job, he will go to this map and check if someone cancels him (the new task will cancel all previous tasks that exists in this map). Your thinking?

Comment: I don’t understand.  Aren’t your tasks independent of each other?

Comment: Yes they are, but I lost my reference to the old task when new one starts... And the old one is checking the status of the new one instead the status of himself...

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, why don't you just fix it, so that the task checks its own status, instead of the status of the incorrect task?

Comment: How can I check the status if the new task override his reference? Some hash map will help here?

Comment: Call `isCancelled()`?

Comment: It's fine when you are within the call method - but what can I do if this method launched another method? Do I need to pass the task to this method?

Comment: I can't see any particularly good reason you would want to know about cancellation outside of the task itself: this just sounds like a bad design. Obviously, you could pass a reference to the task to whatever you are calling, but that introduces some coupling you almost certainly don't want. Also note that cancelling a task interrupts the thread it is running on; so if you are calling an interruptible method, you will immediately receive an `InterruptedException`; if you are calling a non-interruptible blocking method, you can check `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` after it completes.

Comment: I can put all my logic within the call method, but this will be ugly and not modular code. Your idea with interruptible / non-interruptible sounds great. Can you explain a little bit about this two types? How can I know which type my method belongs to? And again, you are really helping here :)

Comment: To clarify: I wasn't suggesting you put everything in the `call()` method: the point I was making it that the methods you call from there would only need to care about cancellation if they had some kind of (cancellable) side effect, which doesn't sound like a good design. For understanding interruption, read this (old, but still good) [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).

Comment: Cool! Issue is solved:)